# Error on SQL query on Access Database

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here is the problem:

```
UPDATE school_new 
  SET school_new.school_id = school.[School ID], 
      school_new.school_address = school.[School Address]
FROM school_new
INNER JOIN school on school_new.school_name = school.[School Name]
```

And I get this error and I can't figure out what is the problem

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'school.[School ID] FROM school_new
>       INNER JOIN school on school_new.school_name = school.[School Name]

Comment: No inner join for UPDATE queries

Comment: Why are you updating the same value twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a slight change in the update query with join on access

```
UPDATE school_new 
INNER JOIN school on school_new.school_name = school.[School Name]
  SET school_new.school_id = school.[School ID], 
      school_new.school_id = school.[School ID]
```

Answer (score 1):

List the tables and join condition before the SET keyword.

```
UPDATE school_new
INNER JOIN school
    ON school_new.school_name = school.[School Name]
SET school_new.school_id = school.[School ID]
```

In your example, you had `school_new.school_id = school.[School ID]` assigned twice; I did that `SET` only once.  This point is important because if you list it twice, the db engine will throw an error...

```
Duplicate output destination 'school_new.school_id'.
```

Based on the update to your question ...

```
UPDATE school_new
INNER JOIN school
    ON school_new.school_name = school.[School Name]
SET school_new.school_id = school.[School ID], 
    school_new.school_address = school.[School Address]
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer works. I made a typo on my question. but using the join first solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

I know this would sound strange but try to create a sample table e.g school_new_Test and in that do not give name with spaces and same way create duplicate table of school e.g school_ORG_Test in that also do not give spaces and then try the above query with new tables and collumn names without spaces.

Answer (score -3):

Generally, 'update' statements can't have a join. Use a nested query thus

```
update school_new
set school_new.school_id = (select school.[school ID]
from school where school.[school name] = school_new.school_name)
```

Comment: @ZafarYousafi: there can be a join in an update statement if the table to be updated is aliased (see stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/sql-update-with-join). There is, however, no aliasing in the above question.

Comment: That's not true. You can use updates with joins no matter of the table is aliased or not. Plus, this question is about MS Access SQL, and the question you linked is not.